# Google oauth fatal error:count() using php 8.0.9 version

Tags: php, authentication, google-oauth, guzzle, google-signin

Config.php

```
<?php

//start session on web page
session_start();

//config.php

//Include Google Client Library for PHP autoload file
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Make object of Google API Client for call Google API
$google_client = new Google_Client();

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client ID
$google_client->setClientId('xxx');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client Secret key
$google_client->setClientSecret('xxx');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URI
$google_client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/gauth/index.php');

// to get the email and profile 
$google_client->addScope('email');

$google_client->addScope('profile');

?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php

//index.php

//Include Configuration File
include('config.php');

$login_button = '';


if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{

 $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);


 if(!isset($token['error']))
 {
 
  $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

 
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];


  $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);

 
  $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();

 
  if(!empty($data['given_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['family_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['email']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['gender']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_gender'] = $data['gender'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['picture']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
  }
 }
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{

 $login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'">Login With Google</a>';
}

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHP Login using Google Account</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">PHP Login using Google Account</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <?php
   if($login_button == '')
   {
    echo '<div class="panel-heading">Welcome User</div><div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION["user_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail" />';
    echo '<h3><b>Name :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].' '.$_SESSION['user_last_name'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><b>Email :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_email_address'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</h3></div>';
   }
   else
   {
    echo '<div align="center">'.$login_button . '</div>';
   }
   ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error after i hit the login button and select a google account.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:67 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(67): count(NULL) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(107): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->release(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle)) #2
 C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #4
 C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #5 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(72): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #6 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(30): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #7
 C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php(68): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #8 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(57): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #9 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #10 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(268): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #11 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #12 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(104): GuzzleHttp\Client->sendAsync(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #13 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\google\auth\src\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php(34): GuzzleHttp\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #14
 C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(492): Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #15 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(184): Google\Auth\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken(Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler)) #16 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\index.php(14): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('4/0AX4XfWibPpYp...') #17 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\gauth\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
```

From what i understand , i am getting the error on line 14 of the index.php file that is while fetching the access token but i followed the exact steps in the documentation.
I also read somewhere that it is because of the new version of php.
How do i fix this ?
I have installed composer and google/apiclient:"^2.0"

Comment: Did you check that google/apiclient 2.0 supports PHP 8

Comment: Yes, the documentation says that PHP 5.6.0 or higher is required so i assume that includes php 8

Comment: something you are passing as a parameter is not an array and shoudl be